# In an R Markdown document, "includes" for docx output?

Tags: ms-word, latex, r-markdown

In the .Rmd below I have `includes: in_header:` for pdf output and `includes: before_body:` for docx output. Is there something analogous for docx output?

My current hack is to include the `<!--- For DOCX Only --->` code chunk conditionally when producing docx output. But I'd prefer not to have this clutter up the body of my .Rmd and move it out into some sort of `preamble-word.tex` file.

## tinytextest.Rmd

````
---
title: "TinyTeX Test"
author: "Me"
date: "5/3/2019"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    includes:
      before_body: preamble-mathjax.tex
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble-v02.tex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<!--- For DOCX Only --->
`r if (!knitr:::is_latex_output() & !knitr:::is_html_output()) '
\\newcommand{\\mathbbm}[1]{\\mathbf{#1}}
'`

Hello

\[\mathbbm{1}_{S}(x)\]
````

## preamble-mathjax.tex

```
\(\\newcommand{\\mathbbm}[1]{\\mathbf{#1}}\)
```

## preamble.tex

```
\usepackage{bbm}
```