# R Markdown document with html/docx output, using LaTeX package bbm?

Tags: html, r, ms-word, latex, r-markdown

How can I use the LaTeX package `bbm` in an R markdown for html/docx output?

Currently I'm using the hack solution below where, essentially, I just abandon using the package `bbm` for .docx/.html output. Is there a hack solution in which I can still use the package?

Note, this question related to my question [In an R Markdown document, “includes” for docx output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211083/in-an-r-markdown-document-includes-for-docx-output) where there I'm specifically asking about how to move these special `<!--- For DOCX Only --->` code chunk to a `preamble-word.tex` file to be indcluded in the YAML header. This question is also related to the question [How to get \bm{} to work in an R markdown (to HTML) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226675/how-to-get-bm-to-work-in-an-r-markdown-to-html-file) My current hack for `bbm` is basically an adaptation of one of the hacks proposed as an answer to that question.

## tinytextest.Rmd

````
---
title: "TinyTeX Test"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{bbm}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<!--- For HTML Only --->
`r if (knitr:::is_html_output()) '
$\\newcommand{\\mathbbm}[1]{\\mathbf{#1}}$
'`

<!--- For DOCX Only --->
`r if (!knitr:::is_latex_output() & !knitr:::is_html_output()) '
\\newcommand{\\mathbbm}[1]{\\mathbf{#1}}
'`

Hello

\[\mathbbm{1}_{S}(x)\]
````

## .pdf output

[image]

## .docx/.html output

[image]

Comment: I have just run into this same issue. Apparently, there's no solution yet that anyone knows about...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, another answer, I just realized, these are two slightly different questions - one by the question starter and one by the bounty starter.

> I would need a solution to this issue as well. Here is my minimum
> example expected to work:
>
> ````
> ---
> title: "Testing LaTeX packages in Docx format" 
> output: word_document 
> header-includes:
>   - \usepackage{xfrac} 
> --- 
>   $$ \sfrac{1}{2} $$ ```
> ````

In this case the outlined answer with MathJax will not work so well. sfrac is not supported by MathJax (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html)

I don't know if you need \sfrac specifically, but \frac or \tfrac would be supported. Maybe you can use these instead.

Here an example with \frac

```
 ---
 title: "Frac Test"
 header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{xfrac}
 output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

$$
   \frac{1}{2}+1
$$
```

Output of \frac example html:

[image]

This will work for .pdf / word and html.

Here an example with \tfrac

```
---
title: "TFrac Test"
header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{xfrac}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

$$
   \tfrac{1}{2}+1
$$
```

Output \tfrac example html:

[image]

This will run for html, pdf - for word it will write 1/2 instead of a formula, since there is no \tfrac equivalent in word.

\cfrac and \dfrac are also supported by MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

You can somehow solve this for most of the important symbols/characters via Mathjax. Here is a list of supported symbols/characters:http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html
Just look there for the symbol you need.

Then you use it like this:

```
$$
\require{mhchem}
\begin{equation}
  [C] + [R] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_1}
  [CR] + [C] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-2}]{k_2}
  [C2R]
(\#eq:multiplebinding)
\end{equation}
$$
```

So you need to enclose your command in $$. In this example \xrightleftharpoons was used. From the table I linked you above you can see that you need to add \require{mhchem} in this case. For your case this isn't needed, you just need to write \mathbb.

Example:

````
  ---
title: "TinyTeX Test"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathbbol}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Hello Mori, this should work


$$
    \mathbb{1}_{S}(x)
$$

Greetings, Steffen
````

HTML OUTPUT:
[image]

WORD OUTPUT:
[image]

Also note, that I replaced bbm with \usepackage{mathbbol} - otherwise it had errors rendering the pdf for me. Here a discussion about bbm on tex.stackexchange ... most people advise against using bbm, since there are better packages to get the symbols https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after Steffen's answers, I've come to the conclusion that the proper answer would be: **Including LaTeX packages in `docx` documents cannot be done** (at least up to now).

The only solution is to use the equivalent MathJax-supported command/symbol. Nevertheless, Steffen's answer pointed me in the correct direction of the commands supported by MathJax (many thanks!), so I awarded him the bounty.

Also, as my specific problem was with diagonal fractions, I tried all the `frac` variants allegedly supported by MathJax. There are six of them, out of which the following worked: `\dfrac`, `\frac`, and `\dfrac`, and the following did not: `\cfrac`, `\flatfrac`, and `\genfrac`.